# Regex to separate string values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a REGEX that will match version numbers and put it into an array. The problem is the version numbers aren't consistent. Some have text after it e.g Rev,Phase,Release which sometimes has more text after that e.g Patch 001, Delta, Lib.

The REGEX I've made has two flaws. 1 if the third digit has a value larger than 9 if fails, and 2 it's not matching the double digit after "Patch". How would I resolve this?

REGEX:
`arDOORSValues = DOORSVal.match(/(\d{1,}[.]\d+[.]\d{1,2}?){1}\s?(Rev|Phase|Release)?\s?[a-zA-z]*(-)?\s?(Patch\s?\d+|Delta|Lib|TBD)?/g);`

Test String:
4.1.04.3.5 Rev -4.3.5 Rev A4.3.5 Rev A Delta4.2.134.3.3Lib4.3.5 Patch 001

Expected Output: An array of SW Values. e.g "4.1.0,4.3.5 Rev -,4.3.5 Rev A,4.3.5 Rev A Delta,4.2.13,4.3.3Lib,4.3.5 Patch 001"

Color coded REGEX and Test String
[image]

[image]

`(\d{1,}[.]\d+[.]\d{1,2}?){1}\s?(Rev|Phase|Release)?\s?[a-zA-z]*(-)?\s?(Patch\s?\d+|Delta|Lib|TBD)` I removed the question mark after the (Patch....) or code. But it only matches 4.3.5 Rev A Delta, 4.3.5 Patch 001.
[image]

`(\d{1,}[.]\d+[.]\d{1,2}?){1}\s?(Rev|Phase|Release)?\s?[a-zA-z]*(-)?\s?(Patch\s?\d+|Delta|Lib|TBD)*` Doesn't match the double digit after 4.2.13. It only matches the 4.2.1.
[image]

`(\d{1,}[.]\d+[.]\d{1,2}?){1}\s?(Rev|Phase|Release)?\s?[a-zA-z]*(-)?\s?(Patch\s?\d+|Delta|Lib|TBD)?` Doesn't match the double digit in 4.2.13 and Patch numeric text.
[image]

Comment: Rev -4? How does that work? Also please share your expected output

Comment: Where is that input string coming from? Why doesn't it use separators between versions? I can't even parse the individual versions by eye. And the fact that `4.2.134.3.3` are actually two version numbers that aren't separated seems just utterly insane to me.

Comment: The output is from a database and they don't use any delimiter to separate the values. I've requested they fix this but was told "NO".

Comment: Then I would tell them GIGO.

Comment: So you're saying that string is stored as we see it in your question inside a singular cell of some DB table? Or is it a concatenation of multiple DB cell values?

Comment: Provided `^\d\.\d+\.\d` matches each individual version number (mainly that it begins with a single digit followed by a period) perhaps you could split the string at (zero-width) matches of `(?<!\.|^)(?=\d\.\d+\.\d.*?)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qHARkm/1). Note that if the version number could begin with two or more digits there would be no unambiguous way to split, for example, `"1.1.111.1.1"`.

Comment: Try `(\d+[.]\d+[.](?=(\d{1,2}(?!\.)))\2)\s?(Rev|Phase|Release)?\s?(?!Patch|Delta|TBD)[a-zA-Z]*(-)?\s?(Patch\s?\d+|Delta|Lib|TBD)?` https://regex101.com/r/BRPHul/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split between not a dot and a number matching the version format.

Disclaimer: your string could contain an unresolvable flaw: it's impossible to distinguish version in `4.2.134.3.3`. It could be 4.2.1 and 34.3.3 or 4.2.13 and 4.3.3. Assuming the last, the first part of the version should be 1 digit.

```js
const str = '4.1.04.3.5 Rev -4.3.5 Rev A4.3.5 Rev A Delta4.2.134.3.3Lib4.3.5 Patch 001';

const revs = str.split(/(?<=[^.])(?=\d\.\d+\.\d+)/g);

console.log(revs);
```

Expression breakdown:

```
/         START EXPRESSION
  (?<=    START POSITIVE LOOKBEHIND
    [^.]  NOT DOT LITERAL
  )       END POSITIVE LOOKBEHIND
  (?=     START POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD
    \d    DIGIT
    \.    DOT LITERAL
    \d+   DIGIT (ONE OR MORE)
    \.    DOT LITERAL
    \d+   DIGIT (ONE OR MORE)
  )       END POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD
/         END EXPRESSION
  g       FLAGS [GLOBAL]
```

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl what have you used to generate it?

Comment: I'm getting a JSLint error "M:\TriggerScripts\GA\ircDOORStoIntegrityMapping.js(675): SyntaxError: invalid quantifier ?
         arRevs = DOORSVal.split(/(?<=[^.])(?=\d\.\d+\.\d+)/g);"
And when I try to run it in the database I get this error "undefined: identifier is a reserved word" line 675 "arRevs = DOORSVal.split(/(?<=[^.])(?=\d\.\d+\.\d+)/g);"

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I did it by hand.

Comment: @JenPann JSLint has nothing to do to the problem, that's another question. You asked how to get the versions. Does my answer resolves this particular question of yours. If so, don't hesitate to accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, wow, pretty cool

Comment: @JenPann ask another question about JSLint